# How can I prevent a bootable USB flash drive from being unusable after the Ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I have already installed Ubuntu in the past. After the installation, my bootable USB flash drive became unusable for booting and using the system. That was very frustrating because I still wanted to be able to use Ubuntu live on my other computer.

Now I have an USB with persistent memory and having Ubuntu installation media. I made it with persistent memory to be able to store file in my live sessions. I need to install Ubuntu and Im afraid of losing the persistent data or not being able to use Ubuntu live with the USB flash drive again. What should I do to perform the installation avoiding losing data or making the USB unusable for booting on Ubuntu live.

Comment: No special steps are needed, as it should remain bootable, unless you overwrite something during the installation.

Comment: If you fill the Persistence partition, "casper-rw" or "writable", the drive will become unbootable. Filling the persistence file/partition will not effect the Live boot. What tool did you use to make the drive? Some tools are limited to a 4GB persistent file and some will make an unlimited size persistent partition. once the persistent file/partition is mounted the data can be copied to a larger persistence file or partition.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I used mkusb and I set the persistent memory to 100% while making the USB bootable. Can I use it to install Ubuntu without the risk of it becoming unusable

Comment: Yes you can use it in Live mode no problem at all. Live mode does not touch the persistent partition. Since mkusb uses a persistent  partition, you can open Disks and it will show you if you have space left in the casper-rw or writable partitions. if not you can clone your USB to a larger USB and increase it's size using GParted, all in one shot.

Comment: A full partition for persistence is a common reason why persistent live mode fails. But there are other reasons too. Sometimes the file system in the partition for persistence gets corrupted, or some system file or files gets damaged. In these cases it helps to repair the file system and/or if things are bad, to delete all files in the partition for persistence. If you want a smooth ride, it is a good idea to take backups. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_and_restore_of_persistent_overlay_data).